# List lags on scroll with overlay

Tags: swift, swiftui, overlay, swiftui-list

I have a list with simply overlay(I want to make header with blur background, so that's why I use it like overlay), and when I start scroll, it becomes laggy until first row is disappear under overlay. There are no lags if I use LazyVStack, but it has worse performance in general, so I have to use List.

Additional info:
There are +-1000 elements in List, but it doesn't lag without overlay.
List cell contains image and 4 Texts, but it lags even with 1 Text inside cell.
Header has background with UIBlurEffect, it lags with Color as well.

Samples:

```
List {
    Spacer(minLength: headerHeight)
                    
    ForEach(elements, id: \.self) { element in
        //CELL VIEW
    }
}
.overlay(header, alignment: .top)
```

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicator: false) {
    Spacer(minLength: headerHeight) 
    
    LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {                
        ForEach(elements, id: \.self) { element in
            //CELL VIEW
        }
    }
}
.overlay(header, alignment: .top)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would need more code in order to test what exactly the problem is, but using [drawingGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/drawinggroup(opaque:colormode:)) on your header could reduce expensive effect draw calls and fix the lag.

Also, consider using a [sticky section header](https://swiftuirecipes.com/blog/sticky-list-header-in-swiftui) instead of a spacer and an overlay. This could also improve performance.

Comment: Drawing group doesn't support UIBlurEffect. Just tried to use sticky section header, and it lags as well

Comment: I'm trying to create header similar to default large/collapsible style. But I can't use NavigationView due to project limitations, so creating my own one

Comment: Found a lags reason. That was a method to read first element position(I have used it to know list offset). It was based on GeometryReader & position onChange. But then how can I get list offset?

Comment: Could you use `.blur` instead of `UIBlurEffect`?